Exporting shapefile from Civil3D to QGIS goes to wrong location
I am trying to export shapefiles from Civil3D to QGIS. My Civil3D drawing is set to NAD83 Pennsylvania State Planes, North Zone, ft" (EPSG 2271), and my QGIS file is set to the same coordinate system in the project settings. When I export shapefiles from CAD using the "MAPEXPORT" command, my shapes are shown in the correct location when viewed in Google Earth (Pennsylvania), but in QGIS they show up in the Republic of Congo in Africa. When I export the shapefile from Google Earth to QGIS as a KML file, it still appears in Africa. What setting do have wrong in QGIS? All layers and project are in the correct projection.

Just drag-n-drop your shapefile into QGIS. Don't set anything. Does that work?

Are you sure your Layer is set to EPSG 2271 ? not only the QGIS project l. Otherwise please share screenshots of your Qgis interface if possible

Are you sure your shapefile has the correct projection information?  We used to see lots of CAD created files with no projection information.  A shapefile consists of multiple files with the same name and different extension.  If you are using Windows in Windows Explorer can you see a prj file as part of the shapefile collection.  If not, then you will need to assign a projection to the shapefile which you an do in QGIS layer properties.  But be sure that is the layer's actual CRS.  If you see a prj open it in a text editor and be sure it shows the correct CRS.

I know the what, just not how you did it. Your 2271 coordinates in 3857 land in Africa.
